# How do I pass an objectId through a URL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a new programmer who is trying to learn how to create a CRUD application. I am trying to pass an objectID as a parameter through a URL.

```
<tr>
      <td>{{this.Name}}<hr></td>
      <td>{{this.Email}}<hr></td>
      <td>{{this.Phone}}<hr></td>
      <td>
           <a href="/contacts/delete/<%= this._id %>">Delete</a>
      </td>
</tr>
```

After passing the parameter I am trying to display the ID on another page with this code:

```
app.get('/contacts/delete/:id', function(req, res){
    const ContactId = new ObjectId(req.params.id);
    res.send(ContactId); 
});
```

When I run my API I am getting this error:

Cannot GET /contacts/delete/%3C%25=%20this._id%20%25%253E

Comment: Looks like you are trying to interpolate the id with the url but it's being encoded literally, do you know which template engine you're using?

Comment: I am using Express Handlebars

Comment: If you're using Handlebars you should be using `{{ }}` syntax for expressions

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error, but I am still getting the same error:      Cannot GET /delete/5e482fcad9e6ab0b56bc7ba4

Comment: ***Update*** I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be this:

```
<tr>
      <td>{{this.Name}}<hr></td>
      <td>{{this.Email}}<hr></td>
      <td>{{this.Phone}}<hr></td>
      <td>
           <a href="/contacts/delete/{{this._id}}>">Delete</a>
      </td>
</tr>
```